# accessing plugin variables in td-agent/fluentd config

Tags: fluentd

I've got a fluentd config that i'm using to push logs to cloudwatch logs, and i'd like to extract a certain piece of the container name to use as the log group name.  I see that i can embed ruby expressions in my config, but i can't figure out how to access the "container_name" variable from inside that embedded expression.  is this possible?

this is my config, which works but uses the raw `container_name` value as the log group name.

```
<match container.**>
  @type cloudwatch_logs
  region us-west-2
  log_group_name container_name
  log_stream_name "#{File.open('/etc/machine-id').read.strip()}"

  auto_create_stream true
  retention_in_days  7
</match>
```

this is what i want to do, but `container_name` is not defined in the embedded ruby expression

```
<match container.**>
  @type cloudwatch_logs
  region us-west-2
  log_group_name "#{container_name.match(/\w+/)[0]}"
  log_stream_name "#{File.open('/etc/machine-id').read.strip()}"

  auto_create_stream true
  retention_in_days  7
</match>
```

is this possible?